# php - xmlseclibs can't sign the node i want

Tags: php, sign, xmlseclibs

I've been signing work-related xml for almost a year, and today i noticed that i was doing it wrong (please excuse my bad english, it's not my primary language)

I use the xmlseclibs library for php, and i want the signatures to be like this:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
<SignatureMethod
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
<Reference URI="#XXXXX">
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
<DigestValue>... </DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>... </SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>... </X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

The following example should help me to demonstrate what i want to do.
We have the following xml file:

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    somedata
  </node2>
</node1>
```

And after i sign it, looks like this:

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    somedata
  </node2>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
<SignatureMethod
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
<Reference URI="#XXXXX">
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
<DigestValue>... </DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>... </SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>... </X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</node1>
```

Now, that's the structure i need, however, when i do this, the sign is applied over **all** the document (node1 and node2) but i only want to sign the node2 (that's the error im getting, i noticed it thanks to the DigestValue).

But when i do that, i got the following:

```
<node1>
  <node2>
    somedata
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
<SignatureMethod
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
<Reference URI="#XXXXX">
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
<DigestValue>... </DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>... </SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>... </X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

I've trying for days, but i can't place the signature where i want it to be (just under the tag that's been signed, not inside).

Any thoughts?

The function i'm using is something like this:

```
function firmarEnvio2($xmlr){
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xml = file_get_contents($xmlr);
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->encoding = 'ISO-8859-1';

$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig(FALSE); 
$objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::C14N);

echo "<pre>";
$options['prefix'] = '';
$options['prefix_ns'] = '';
$options['force_uri'] = TRUE;
$options['id_name'] = 'ID';

$objDSig->addReference($doc, XMLSecurityDSig::SHA1, array(XMLSecurityDSig::TR_ENV_SIG), $options);

/*
$objDSig->addReference($doc->documentElement, XMLSecurityDSig::SHA1,
array(
'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature',
'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#'
),
array('id_name' => 'Id', 'overwrite' => false));


*/

$objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, array('type'=>'private'));

$pass = "some string";
$pfx =   file_get_contents("someroute/certificate.pfx");
openssl_pkcs12_read($pfx, $key, $pass);

$objKey->loadKey($key["pkey"]);
$objDSig->add509Cert($key["cert"]);

$tag="x";

//the following is to compare the digest that i want with the one i always got
echo "<br><br>Digest1<br>";
print_r (base64_encode(sha1($doc->documentElement->C14N(), true)));

echo "<br><br>Digest2<br>";
print_r (base64_encode(sha1($doc->documentElement->getElementsByTagName($tag)->item(0)->C14N(), true)));

print_r ($firma);
$objDSig->sign($objKey, $doc->documentElement);


//print_r($doc);
$doc->save('test_s.xml');
return true;
}
```

does anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue with the xmlseclibs library.
Here's what worked for me:

```
function signXML($xml) {

    $doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $doc->loadXML($xml);
    $objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig('');
    $objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::EXC_C14N);
    $node = $objDSig->addObject($doc->documentElement);
    $objDSig->addReference(
        $node, 
        XMLSecurityDSig::SHA1
    );
    $objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, array('type'=>'private'));
    $privkey = $this->serverroot.'/certs/dev.key';
    $objKey->loadKey($privkey, TRUE);
    $objDSig->sign($objKey);
    $pubkey = $this->serverroot.'/certs/dev-pub.cer';
    $objDSig->add509Cert(file_get_contents($pubkey));
    $node->ownerDocument->encoding = "UTF-8";
    $node->ownerDocument->save(dirname(__FILE__).'/test.xml');

    return $node->ownerDocument->saveXML();
}
```

Hope it can be of help.

Comment: No call to $objDSig->appendSignature($node) was needed? Interesting.